# I dont know why my SpringBoot dont starts

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, repository

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'codeService' defined in file [...\CodeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'codeRepository' defined in platform.CodeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class platform.CodeContext

2022-11-19 20:36:42.372  WARN 18200 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'codeService' defined in file [...\CodeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'codeRepository' defined in platform.CodeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class platform.CodeContext

i have this eror and this warn do you know what is wrong?

```
package platform;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CodeRepository extends JpaRepository<CodeContext, Long> {


}
```

```
package platform;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CodeService {


    private final  CodeRepository codeRepository;

    public CodeContext getCodeAt(Long n) {
        return codeRepository.findById(n)
                .orElseThrow(CodeNotFoundException::new);
    }


    public List<CodeContext> getLastTen() {
        List<CodeContext> temporary = new ArrayList<>();
        long lastTen = codeRepository.count();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            temporary.add(this.getCodeAt(lastTen));
            lastTen--;
            if (lastTen <= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return temporary;
    }

    public void saveCode(CodeContext code) {
        code.nowTime();
        codeRepository.save(code);
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
}
```

```
server.port=8889

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:../snippets
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

i dont know what to do i tried googling about it but i dont find anything

Answer (score 0):

Add @Entity to your class CodeContext